# Mysql INNER JOIN doubts

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

my query is as follows:

```sql
SELECT * FROM order_main t
  LEFT JOIN order_pos op ON t.id=op.order_main_id
  LEFT JOIN order_product oprod ON op.id=oprod.order_pos_id
  LEFT JOIN product pr ON pr.id=oprod.product_id
  INNER JOIN(
              SELECT t.id, MAX(pr.hours) as HoursMax FROM order_main t
                LEFT JOIN order_pos op ON t.id=op.order_main_id
                LEFT JOIN order_product oprod ON op.id=oprod.order_pos_id
                LEFT JOIN product pr ON pr.id=oprod.product_id
              WHERE (t.created <= '2013-07-01' AND t.status >= 1 AND t.status < 3 AND pr.hours IS NOT NULL)
                    OR (t.created > '2013-07-01' AND t.payed = 1 AND t.report_sended = 0 AND pr.hours IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY t.id
            ) grouptt ON t.id = grouptt.id
WHERE (t.created <= '2013-07-01' AND t.status >= 1 AND t.status < 3 AND pr.hours IS NOT NULL AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL grouptt.HoursMax HOUR) > t.created)
      OR (t.created > '2013-07-01' AND t.payed = 1 AND t.report_sended = 0 AND pr.hours IS NOT NULL AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL grouptt.HoursMax HOUR) > t.created)
```

Is there a way to do without INNER JOIN?

**UPDATE:**

I'm trying to select all orders which are in late.

I have hours in my table product as you can see i need to find all positions(order_pos) of order(order_main) and from they i need to find relations(order_product) and only then i can find my product hours(product). But positions with products may be several for each order. And i need to find MAX product hours.

When i'm finding MAX product hours from each orders(now i do it with INNER JOIN) i can compare this with order creation date(t.created).

I think that this sql query is very complicated. It seems that i can do this more easier?

Thanks

Comment: It would be better if you could explain what are you trying to achieve, not just throwing a piece of code into the public.

Comment: Why do you need this to not be an inner join?  What behavioural or performance issue are you trying to resolve?

Comment: Sorry... updated my post with info.....

Comment: What fields do you _need_ in your result table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you only need the fields from order_main, you can at least get rid of the joins
and conditions in the outer query (and use *only* inner joins):

```
SELECT * FROM order_main om
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT t.id, t.created
     FROM order_main t
     INNER JOIN order_pos op ON t.id = op.order_main_id
     INNER JOIN order_product oprod ON op.id = oprod.order_pos_id
     INNER JOIN product pr ON pr.id = oprod.product_id
     WHERE (t.created <= '2013-07-01' AND t.status IN (1,2))
     OR (t.created > '2013-07-01' AND t.payed = 1 AND t.report_sended = 0)
     GROUP BY t.id
     HAVING DATE_ADD(t.created, INTERVAL MAX(pr.hours) HOUR) < NOW()) AS grouptt
ON om.id = grouptt.id
```